# when I install gitlab-ce through docker on m1 mac mini, it stucks on gitlab::database::migrations

Tags: macos, gitlab, apple-m1, silicon

this is my run commad:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname localgitlab.com \
  --publish 9443:443 --publish 9980:80 --publish 9922:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume ~/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab: \
  --volume ~/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab: \
  --volume ~/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab: \
  --platform linux/amd64 --privileged=true \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

---

but it stops here

```
Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations

  * ruby_block[check remote PG version] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)

  * rails_migration[gitlab-rails] action run
```

---

I'm not sure if I can use a m1 mac as a gitlab server?

And I set up gitlab successful on my inter chip mac.

Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No url and nothing

Comment: March 2022, I'm still facing the same issue, Did anyone of you guys figure out the error?

Comment: Same problem here and seemingly there is no solution yet

Answer (score 2):

There is a [post in Gitlab forums discussing this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/6659) but there is no solution.

The only solution I found so far is to use the [yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8](https://hub.docker.com/r/yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8) image instead of the official GitLab one. This image is built with arm64 compatibility and released at the same time as the official image.

A similar image with the EE version of GitLab is here [gsdukbh/gitlab-ee-arm64](https://hub.docker.com/r/gsdukbh/gitlab-ee-arm64), it is maintained but it doesn't contain all the versions.

BTW, this is my docker-compose.yml tested on a Mac M1 if you want to give it a try:

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.local'
    container_name: gitlab-ce
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    links:
      - postgresql:postgresql
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        postgresql['enable'] = true
        gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab"
        gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "gitlab"
        gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "postgresql"
        gitlab_rails['db_port'] = "5432"
        gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "gitlabhq_production"
        gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
        gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
        external_url 'http://gitlab.local'
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8043:443"
      - "8022:22"
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab
  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:13.6-alpine
    container_name: gitlab-postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gitlab
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitlab
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitlabhq_production
      - TZ=America/Bogota
      - PGDATA=/data
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab-db-data:/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: I tried to use your yml file, but postgres is logging errors:

gitlab-ce        | 2023-10-23_15:18:36.24631 LOG:  could not set permissions of file "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432": Invalid argument
gitlab-ce        | 2023-10-23_15:18:36.24640 WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql"
gitlab-ce        | 2023-10-23_15:18:36.24651 FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
gitlab-ce        | 2023-10-23_15:18:36.24951 LOG:  database system is shut down